# Port Qt app with QtDBus on android

Tags: android, qt, qtdbus

I have an app written in Qt and it uses QtDBus. I need to port it on android. Do not have much experience with both technologies.

when I try to compile my Qt app for android I get am getting an error:

```
fatal error: QtDBus/QtDBus: No such file or directory
```

in line

```
#include <QtDBus/QtDBus>
```

Compilation for desktop goes as it should

I have found info that dbus is not supported by android(or is it outdated info?). Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have found info that dbus is not supported by android(or is it
>   outdated info?). Is there any way to do so?

Short answer: not for now.

dbus has not been supported on Android for a while, so QtDBus will not be supported for now respectively.

Comment: Wait, does that mean dbus was supported at one time? I thought it had never been supported on Android.